# Extra whitespace appended within a tag element's text in tika parser

Tags: html-parsing, apache-tika

**Website**: http://www.thevanitycase.com/about-us.php

While parsing the content of the page using Tika Parser, extra whitespace ("  ") is appended in the text "Tel: +91-22-61801700".

That is,

**Expected text:** "Tel: +91-22-61801700"

**Actual text:** "Tel: +91-22-6180170  0"

The JS path of the element: body > div > div:nth-child(6) > div > div.footer-full.footer-btm > div > p > span

Usually, double whitespace will be appended between every tag element text. But here double whitespace is appended within a tag element text.

**Components used:**

- Tika parser 1.20
- Tika core
- Crawler4j

**Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: It looks like there's a getEnableAutoSpace option, but you would need to actually edit the Tika Java code; you couldn't just use the Tika server jar as-is. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-724